# Uniqueness conditions for linear transport equation with nonconstant velocity

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, regularity, hyperbolic-pde

Considering the following equation,
$$
u_t + \operatorname{div} \, (u \, \mathbf{b}(\mathbf{x},t)) = 0
$$
in a cylinder $K = \{(\mathbf{x},t) \in \Omega \times (0,T) \}$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is regular (whatever we need), with initial condition 
$$u |_{t=0} = u_0$$
and 
$$\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0$$ at the boundary of $\Omega$, 
what are the conditions (necessary or sufficient) on $\mathbf{b}$ for this homogeneous equation to have unique solution in $L^2 (K)$?

I have seen something like $\operatorname{div} \, ( \mathbf{b}(\mathbf{x},t) ) \geq 0$ but I cannot find a reference to be sure if it is right. As far as I remember, we need the characteristics not to intersect each other but how to ensure that?

Any precise statements or references to them are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at Di-Perna Lions theory ?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. After a quick glance, I cannot understand results there - there is no conditions on the sign of $b$ (if reducing to 1d case), which seems strange, because I believe there should be for initial-value problem for equation $u_t + b(x) u_x + c(x) u=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer comes from a quite simple energy argument.
After multiplying the equation by $u$, integrating by parts and using
$$
\pmb{b} \cdot \nabla u = \operatorname{div} ( \pmb{b} u ) - \left( \operatorname{div} \pmb{b} \right) u, 
$$
one can get
$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \int_{\Omega} u^2 d\Omega = - \int_{\Omega} \left(\operatorname{div} \pmb{b} \right) u^2 d\Omega \leq 0,
$$
if $\operatorname{div} \pmb{b} \geq 0$. So this condition implies uniqueness which I actually sought for.